# How to print the name of the image which is read in every iteration of the for loop in python

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, path

I am trying to find all the grayscale images inside a folder named "train". For that, my code is

```
for img in glob.glob("Tensorflow/workspace/images/train/*.jpg"):
    image = imread(img)
    if(len(image.shape) < 3):
        print('gray')
        # print(image)
        # print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        # print(__file__)
        # print(os.path.basename('image'))
    elif len(image.shape) == 3:
        print('Color(RGB)')
    else:
        print('others')
```

I have tried a lot of ways to do so ( the commented part in my code), but they print the path of the python file like `e:\Desktop\RealTimeFaceRecognition---Microsoft-Engage\Tensorflow\scripts\rgb_checker.py`
But I want to print the image name every time it is in grayscale, for example, if image "`mask43`" is found to be grayscale, then I want to print `E:\Desktop\RealTimeFaceRecognition---Microsoft-Engage\Tensorflow\workspace\images\train\mask43`, which is the path of the image, not the python file inside which I am checking this.

Please tell me the required code to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You have a for loop which have a variable `img` in the for loop that keeps track of which file it is. So that means you can access current file that's in the list by `print(os.path.dirname(img))`